# Is it possible to simulate `md-selected-item` on ng-blur in angular-material md-autocomplete?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm creating this angular app using angular-material where md-autocomplete is very helpful. The form allows users to select or enter data in a field, and the next field populates the data based on the value from the first md-autocomplete field. If the user selects the item from the list, then `md-selected-item=ctrl.selectedText` has the object that I need for the next field. However, if the user only copies a value and pastes in the md-autocomplete field and tabs to the next field, the value is not populated because `ctrl.selectedText` is `null`. Is there a way where I can simulate `md-selected-item` on `ng-blur`?

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle/pen?

Comment: @JohnSmith, here's the pen you requested: http://codepen.io/kunikoho/pen/bpXvLy. As you will see in the codepen that when you start typing, it'll show you the names matching the query text in the dropdown list. But if you hit tab instead of selecting then the selected name is blank. Is there any way hitting the tab will also simulate clicking an item and selecting it? Some users are copying and pasting the information instead of typing and selecting from the list.

Comment: Is the issue only with copy and paste? What I mean by that is: is it enough for you that on paste it would select the exact match, or should it explicitly work with tab?

Comment: I don't want to seem choosy, but preferably both. Sometimes, people not only copy paste, they also type in the entire name instead of selecting from the drop down (cause they don't want to move their hand from keyboard to mouse, and I hear about it all the time how much time they spend doing just that) and also hit tab. I guess for tab, I can listen for tab keycode and copy the selected item (am I wrong?), but how can I do this for Copy and Paste?

Comment: Alright, well, I'll write an answer see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, you'll have to manually listen for the `TAB` key. https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4697 - Clearly states this feature won't be added to the library.

On the other hand, for the copy-paste issue you could add `md-select-on-match` directive to your autocomplete. This should automatically select the option on exact match. You might consider using `md-match-case-insensitive` with this option though.

Comment: WOW!! is it really that simple? Well, I can't thank you enough. `md-select-on-match` worked, however, md-match-case-insensitive didn't work. I copied and pasted the same text in lowercase, but it didn't match it. I have one more question: where and how do I find what directives are available. I checked in angular-material site, but didn't find these directives that you mentioned.

Comment: Interesting, it should work. Might be a bug. Docs are there, just down in the directives section: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete

Comment: Ha. Feel stupid right now. I thought I checked it all out, apparently not. Anyway, thanks for pointing me out in the right direction. You've been very helpful.